# Getting rid of quote marks and spaces in a list from a read file

Tags: python-2.7

So in a project I am doing I am trying to read a bunch of lines and put each line of numerical data into a list of numbers. The problem I am having is that instead of the desired outcome of:

```
[1749, 58.0, 62.6, 70.0, 55.7, 85.0, 83.5, 94.8, 66.3, 75.9, 75.5, 158.6, 85.2]
```

I instead get this when I try and put the read line into a list:

```
['1749', '', '', '', '58.0', '', '62.6', '', '70.0', '', '55.7', '', '85.0', '', '83.5', '', '94.8', '', '66.3', '', '75.9', '', '75.5', '158.6', '', '85.2']
```

All I want to know is how to make the numbers regular numbers without the '' around them and how to get the '' entries between the numbers to go away. the code I am using to get the current outcome is this:

```
sun_file = open('sunspot_data.txt', 'r')

line = sun_file.readlines()

x = line[3].rstrip('\n').split(' ')

list2 = list(x)

print list2
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
with open('sunspot_data.txt') as sun_file:
    for _ in range(3): # skip first three lines
        sun_file.readline()

    for line in sun_file:
        numbers = line.rstrip().split()
        new_list = map(float, numbers)

        print new_list
```

- The default mode is 'r', so you don't need it unless you want to be
  explicit
- Use `with` blocks for opening files. They automatically
  close the file for you after you're done using it.
- `rstrip` by
  default splits newlines (and other whitespace characters) and `split`
  automatically splits by spaces.
- `split()` already returns a list, so there is no need to waste time making a copy of it with `list(x)`
- If you only want the 4th line and your file is big, it may be better to just read line by line until you get to the 4th line rather than reading the whole file

Comment: If the file has a lot of lines this is very wasteful because you read them all but only use one.

Comment: It worked! I had tried doing the map() method before but had the list striped and slpit under another name. any reason that did not work?

Comment: @bh2424 What do you mean stripped and split "under another name?"

Comment: A varibale name. I had x = line[3].rstrip(\n).split() and it did not work.

Comment: @bh2424 That's still not exactly clear, but I'll give it a go. The name of the variable has nothing to do with it. In your question, your final list had `''` in it, which can't be converted to floats, so using `map` would have raised an exception.

Comment: This is all great, the only other thing I have to do now is figure out how to do this for 262 lines in my text file. I could probably use the for loop fo this in a way, right?

Comment: @bh2424 You should probably add that to your question. It is not clear above why you only use the 4th line. Do you want to do this to all the lines in the file (assuming there are 262 total lines), only the first 262 lines, all the lines following the third line, or what exactly?

Comment: @bh2424 Either way, yes it sounds like a for loop would do the job well.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been stuck on his for the good part of an hour.

Comment: Oh to answer your previous comment, I am doing this for 262 lines staring at the line I have used in my example.

Comment: @bh2424 Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks again! And the reason I didnt say the before was because I just wanted a base to start on. I didnt want to have like everyone make my project for me haha. But this has honestly been a huge help thank you!